# Radon-Nikodym theorem (proof from Royden)

Tags: measure-theory

> [image]
>
> [image]

This is from Royden text book.  I guess here $E \subset P_{\lambda}$, and $\mu(P_{\lambda}) = 0 \implies \mu(E) = 0 \implies v(E) = 0$. The last $\implies$ results from absolute continuity.   But, why if $\mu(E)>0$, then $v(E) = 0$? Could you explain this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if $\mu(E)>0$ and $\nu(E)<\lambda \mu(E),$ for all $ \lambda>0$,  then taking $\lambda_n =1/n\mu(E)$, you get $\nu(E)\le 1/n$. Now let $n\to \infty.$

Comment: You mean $\lambda_n = 1/(n\mu(E))$, right? But, why $\lambda_n = 1/(n\mu(E))$? Royden just define $\lambda>0$.

Comment: the inequality is true for $any$ value of $\lambda>0,$ so I chose succesively smaller and smaller values, and so $\nu(E)$ is "trapped" between $0$ and $1/n$ and since this is true for all $n$, we must have $\nu(E)=0.$

Comment: Okay, thanks. Could you answer one more question? So, how does this contradict to $\mu(P_{\lambda}) = 0$ for $\lambda>0$?

Comment: If $\nu=0$, we may take $f=0$ and so the theorem is true trivially. So I guess we're assuming that $\nu\neq 0$. Then, if we assume there is no $\lambda>0$ such that $\mu(P_{\lambda})>0$, it must be that $\nu=0$ and that's the contradiction. Or, to put it another way, if $\nu\neq 0$ then there is such a $\lambda$.